# iOS 11 tableView with searchBar issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Please help to determine the reason of such behavior (it's hard to describe by words, so I recorded the short video) https://youtu.be/E2ks0liFX4I

In short words:
Initially it's able to scroll content beneath navigation bar. If press search field - the search bar looks like detached from table view and goes too high and overlapped by status bar (look at increased space between grey border of search bar and first row in the table). After Cancel button pressed - the search bar jumps down and now can't be hided by scrolling.

I'm using UITableViewController.
Search bar initialization in viewDidLoad:

```swift
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

And in StoryBoard:
[tableView settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl0Sc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what u want. I guess u want the search bar to hide when scrolling?
I set searchbar to the navigationItem, then set the hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling property.

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

Comment: searchBar in navigationController is ok. But inside tableViewHeader it is very weird behavior: jumping and wrong margins after searching.

Comment: Hey did u try adding more items to the table? like 20 more. Since u add it in the table header, i mean i won't hide if it does not scroll down.